# Use ui-calendar without watches

Tags: fullcalendar, ui-calendar

I am struggling with slow rendering of ui-calendar whenever I change the date range. On an average month, I have up to 300 events. I have read that the Angular watches on the events are what is slowing the rendering down.

For the application I'm working on, I do not need watches on the events once they are rendered. What's the easiest way to remove those watches? Can I expect this to improve the performance of the calendar?

Answer (score 0):

Check out bindonce [here](https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce).
I believe this is built into framework starting with v1.3.
Nice blog with examples [here](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2014/10/14/exploring-angular-1.3-one-time-bindings.html). Basically inside your template you would use:

```
<p>Hello {{::vm.name}}!</p>
```

This double colon would bind the vm.name variable defined in controller only once (first time it is changed) and then angular would stop watching the variable afterwards.

Comment: Hm, not sure how useful this is with ui-calendar as you don't add events directly via markup.